# Android: ListView divider is transparent

Tags: android, listview, divider

Hey i have a listview filled with "custom" TextViews (just added a mehtod for convenience)

```
mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_session_list, container, false);
mLV = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.session_list);
mLV.setAdapter(SessionManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
mLV.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
mLV.setDividerHeight(20);
mLV.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
```

The ListView is a Fragment of a ViewPager and the only thing shown at screen

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/session_list"
    style="@style/main.list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true">
</ListView>
```

The style for completion

```
<style name="main">
</style>

<style name="main.list">
    <item name="android:divider">#f00</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">4px</item>
</style>

<style name="main.list.item">
    <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#0ff</item>
</style>
```

The divider is not shonw. Instead the yellow background is visible.
Any ideas?

**EDIT:** if I pull up the listview fast enough the top is red. (The "overshoot" part of the scrolling)

Comment: try removing the style="@style/main.list" from listView.

Comment: @RajeshCP does not change it

Comment: Why didn't you set the divider from XML?

Comment: @gunar tried that too. does not work either

Comment: Try delete mlv.Setdivider(new Colordrawable(Color.red)

Comment: already did that. i put set divider and dividerheight in the xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the colour/drawable, you have to set/reset the height of the divider too.
i have tried it out with

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewInstituate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="313dp"                        
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="1.9dp"        
    android:divider="@android:color/holo_red_light"

    >

</ListView>
```

and it works fine.

but this needs api level 14,

```
android:divider="@android:color/holo_red_light"
```

so you can use

```
android:divider="#FFCC00"
```

i checked both. Thank you

in your code `mLV.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));` and
 `<item name="android:divider">#f00</item>` make me confused

Comment: i got rid of all programmatical changes to the listview and tested your solution. It doesn't work for me. It just shows a thin line of the background as "divider". Can the ViewPager needed for swipe mess with the listview somehow?